# Boolean searches on Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

[Boolean Searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/how-do-i-make-search-return-results-that-actually-contain-all-the-search-terms/35646#35646) works on the main SO/SF/SE network of sites, but I was trying to find a job that's *not* in London, so tried *"not London"* (with and without quotes, *NOT London*, *-London* and *!London* in the Where box, but still only find searches matching London in the Where box.

Is there a smart way to exclude London (or anywhere else, for that matter) from careers searches?