# How to search for posts that contain any of a set of words?

Tags: support, search

A long time ago, the Stack Exchange search engine would return posts that matched any one of the search terms. [After complaints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14898/376604), a [new search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/376604) changed that. Now it only returns posts that match all the search terms.

It is possible to OR combine tags, for example:

- "[image-processing] or [fft]" returns [34,893 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing+or+fft)
- "[image-processing] [fft]" returns [274 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing+fft)

But with words this does not work:

- "dipimage" returns [24 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dipimage)
- "diplib" returns [14 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=diplib)
- "dipimage diplib" returns [2 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dipimage+diplib)
- "dipimage or diplib" returns [1 result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dipimage+or+diplib) -- it looks for the word "or" as well!

The [Stack Overflow search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) does not indicate any way of combining word searches with OR (it only references OR in combination with tags). The [Meta Stack Exchange search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) contains the exact same text.

How can I combine searches?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible with the Stack Exchange search engine. I recommend searching for e.g. `site:stackoverflow.com dipimage OR diplib` using a regular search engine. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+dipimage+OR+diplib) are the 187 results found by Google.

[image]

Comment: Yes, of course we can use Google. But it's not really the same, you can't distinguish questions from answers containing those words, see votes, see tags attached to the questions, etc.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Unfortunately, this is the current state of things (it's well known that the in-built search lacks in *many* aspects). If you'd like SE to incorporate a proper OR operator, perhaps make it a [tag:feature-request]?